# Draw Line & Thickness in a Class: method group / OverLoad issue

Tags: c#, class, line, draw, overloading

I'm trying to set up the code for a Line class with it's own thickness besides the DefaultLineThickness I have for my squares and circles. As much as I would like to use g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 25, 40, 126, 126); it needs to be in it's own class and inherited which I've done with the other shapes. I found this topic closest to my issue but its in XAML and anywhere else it's just simple g.DrawLine

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/line-in-wpf/

Trying to make a crude bike out of circles, squares, and lines.

*edit
After enough times of playing around I'm on the brink of my goal. My only problem is that after I plug everything in and set the line thickness to x-number, it's giving me an error that it can't assign the number because of a 'method group'

Form1 Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bicycle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;





        LineOne l1 = new LineOne(new PointF(50, 40));
        l1.setFilledState(false);
        l1.setLineColor(Color.Black);
        l1.setLineThickness = (6);
        //cannot assign to 'setLineThickness' because it is a method group'
        l1.Draw(g);


        sRectangle r2 = new sRectangle(new PointF(151, 160));
        r2.setFilledState(true);
        r2.setLineColor(Color.Green);
        r2.setFilledColor(Color.Honeydew);
        r2.Draw(g);

        sRectangleEmpty r1 = new sRectangleEmpty(new PointF(150, 150));
        r1.setFilledState(false);
        r1.setLineColor(Color.Blue);
        r1.Draw(g);

        sCircle c1 = new sCircle(new PointF(180, 130));
        c1.setFilledState(true);
        c1.setLineColor(Color.Orange);
        c1.setFilledColor(Color.Ivory);
        c1.Draw(g);

        sCircleEmpty c2 = new sCircleEmpty(new PointF(120, 130));
        c2.setFilledState(false);
        c2.setLineColor(Color.Black);
        c2.Draw(g);




    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

The Line Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Bicycle
{
class LineOne : sRectangle

{


    private void setDrawingAttributes()
    {
        const int lenght = 10;

        Pen SmallPen = new Pen(Brushes.DeepSkyBlue);

        SmallPen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Bevel;

        PointF p1 = PointF.Add(location, new Size(-lenght / 2, 0));

    }

    private void init()
    {
        setDrawingAttributes();
    }

    public LineOne()
    {
        init();
    }


    public LineOne(PointF p)
        : base(p)
    {
        init();
    }




    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
    }





}
}
```

The Shape Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Bicycle
{
class Shape
{
    private Color DefaultLineColor = Color.Black;
    private Color DefaultFillColor = Color.Blue;
    private float DefaultLineThickness = 2;
    protected bool bOutLine;
    protected bool bFilled;
    protected Pen pen;
    protected Brush brush;
    protected PointF location;

    private void setDrawingAttributes()
    {
        pen = new Pen(DefaultLineColor, DefaultLineThickness);
        brush = new SolidBrush(DefaultFillColor);
    }

    private void init()
    {
        bOutLine = true;
        setDrawingAttributes();
    }

    public Shape()
    {
        init();
    }

    public Shape(PointF p)
    {
        location = p;
        init();
    }

    public Color getFillColor()
    {
        return (DefaultFillColor);
    }

    public bool getFilledState()
    {
        return (bFilled);
    }

    public Color getLineColor()
    {
        return (DefaultLineColor);
    }

    public float getLineThickness()
    {
        return (DefaultLineThickness);
    }

    public bool getOutLineState()
    {
        return (bOutLine);
    }

    public bool isOutLine()
    {
        return (bOutLine);
    }

    public bool isFilled()
    {
        return (bFilled);
    }

    public void setFilledColor(Color C)
    {
        DefaultFillColor = C;
        setDrawingAttributes();
    }

    public void setLineColor(Color C)
    {
        DefaultLineColor = C;
        setDrawingAttributes();
    }

    public void setLineThickness(float value)
    {
        DefaultLineThickness = value;
        setDrawingAttributes();
    }


    public void setFilledState(bool value)
    {
        bFilled = value;
    }

    public void setOutLineState(bool value)
    {
        bOutLine = value;
    }



}



}
```

Comment: Ah alrighty thanks got it working, also while I noticed I made the mistake of having my line code to g.DrawEllipse(pen, rect); rather than if (bOutLine) g.DrawLine(pen, rect); Similar to how I overridden the code to force my circle to be a circle, I wanted to force a Line to be drawn. I don't know how it was vaild to work when I had it drawing a circle but when I try to draw a line it saying that 'No overload methdod for drawline, takes two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

setLineThickness is a method, not a property.

Change `l1.setLineThickness = (6);` to `l1.setLineThickness(6);` (i.e. remove the equals sign)

Answer (score 1):

Found it, after reviewing a article in regards of Overloads my Line code should had been

```
public override void Draw(Graphics g)
{

    g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(120, 95));

}
```

I'm now getting different strokes of lines when I play with the l1.setLineThickness(1); in my form code.

Thank you for your assist Mr.Williams on the clarification about LineThickness.